# What is the name of the metal base plate wher you can install a vise (or any other tool)?

Tags: tools, installation, bench

[image: Vise mounting plate]

How is this 'base plate' called?

I have a new workbench, and I want to install my main tool on the corner.
I want to be able to use different tool on this corner (a vise, table grinder, a drill press...) so a base plate like this one seem a simple and practical idea.
But I cant find them.
Do this kind of metal plate have a name?

The image is taken from this video: [WHAT VISE IS THE STRONGEST](https://youtu.be/VcbTopj5u7A?t=21)

Comment: `plinth` comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of these table mounted base plates out there. If you've got a wood work bench you might find that this type serves your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The one in that picture is either a custom made one, or they adapted a drill press vise table.

[image]